# Kubernetes - Get value of a specific metadata when using describe command

Tags: kubernetes

When ruining `kubectl describe service MyService` command and can get the details of my kubernetes service as per below sample:
[image]

I am only interested to get the value of **LoadBalancer Ingress** metadata. Is there a way to retrieve this specific metadata using `kubectl describe` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to use the get method and the go-template output :

`kubectl get svc MyService -o go-template --template='{{range .status.loadBalancer.ingress}}{{.ip}}{{end}}'`

Otherwise (but I don't recommend it), use bash tools like grep and cut

```
kubectl describe svc MyService | grep "LoadBalancer Ingress" | cut -d ':' -f2
```

Comment: When I use your first approach the result will be amended to the next line of linux command (I am not sure if you get what I mean), but the second approach works just fine. Why you don't recommend using "grep" ?

Comment: I edited my answer with the get method. You shouldn't normaly have the result amended to the next line. I recommend to use the go-template output because it provides a powerfull output control and a structured way to get information from kubernetes (please also check https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#formatting-output) whereas `kubectl describe` offers nice human-readable output.

Answer (score 0):

How do you define "LoadBalancer Ingress metadata"? The IP address? If so, that information should appear under "IP:", right on top of LoadBalancer Ingress. But the LoadBalancer type service is cloud provider specific.

Do you actually have an IP address assigned to that specific load balancer?